# Leaf Trees - Altura

Tags: haskell

É habitual definirem-se árvores em que a informação
está apenas nas extermidades (leaf trees):

`data LTree a = Tip a | Fork (LTree a) (LTree a)`

Defina sobre este tipo a seguinte função:

`ltHeight :: LTree a -> Int` que calcula a altura de uma árvore.

Answer (score 0):

Usando recursividade, normalmente a solução passa por considerar:

- Árvore sem nós (caso trivial)
- Árvore com nós (caso recursivo)

O tamanho de uma árvore sem nós, ie, apenas a folha, é 0. Como calcular o tamanho de uma árvore com vários nós? Simples, é 1 mais o tamanho da sub-árvore de maior altura.

Sabendo isto, a implementação é simples:

```
ltHeight :: LTree a -> Int
ltHeight (Tip l)    = 0                                 -- Caso trivial
ltHeight (Fork e d) = 1 + max (ltHeight e) (ltHeight d) -- 1 + altura da maior sub-arvore
```

[Fica aqui o link para um exemplo:](https://repl.it/repls/ConsciousMeekBillygoat)